# Not getting dynamic link in the logs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I just came to know about this firebase feature dynamic link. I was trying to use the same in my app but I am not getting the link in my app.
I have created a dynamic link from the console, and I was trying to get the dynamic link but it's returning me null.

Here is my dynamic link details:

```
Deep link
https://mobiefit.com

Android app
com.firstrun.prototyze

Long Dynamic Link

https://t9nxs.app.goo.gl/?link=https://mobiefit.com&apn=com.firstrun.prototyze&afl=https://mobiefit.com

Short Dynamic Link

https://t9nxs.app.goo.gl/rY6Y
```

I have also added the intent filter in my launcher activity:

```
<!-- [START link_intent_filter] -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="https://t9nxs.app.goo.gl/rY6Y"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- [END link_intent_filter] -->
```

Now I am trying to get the dynamic link but it's giving me null

```
 // [START get_deep_link]
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        }


                        // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                        // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                        // account.
                        // ...

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // Display deep link in the UI
                        if (deepLink != null) {
                            Log.e("deepLink",deepLink.toString());
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "getDynamicLink: no link found");
                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                    }
                });
        // [END get_deep_link]
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since I have fixed my code I want to add one more thing which I have learned from my mistake. In order to redirect the user to a particular screen, put the activity name as host in manifest file, like host: ProgramDetail. You should also put the same name in the link in firebase console like https://ProgramDetail?shortcode=abc.

Comment: Did it worked! i am stuck at the same problem unable to start the activity from the deeplink

Comment: @UditKapahi yes it worked for me. Try to put your activity name as host in manifest without .com extension and same put in the dynamic link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing on your Android.manifest on the filter part to:

```
android:host="t9nxs.app.goo.gl/rY6Y"
```

without the 'https://' before it and keep the rest